# Android Mock location don't work with google maps

Tags: android, mocking, maps, location

I created an Android application that mock the gps location, its works great with most of the programs like igo, waze, osmAnd, GPS status and more, but not with google maps that still show the actual position I'm on.

I disabled the gps and network location as well.

Any ideas why is it? how to solve it? Thanks

The code I use:

```
public void setLocation(double latitude, double longitude, double altitude, float bearing, float speed){
    String PROVIDER_NAME = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
    locationManager.addTestProvider(PROVIDER_NAME, false, false, false, false, true, true, true, Criteria.POWER_LOW, Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);

    locationManager.setTestProviderEnabled(PROVIDER_NAME, true);
    locationManager.setTestProviderStatus(PROVIDER_NAME, LocationProvider.AVAILABLE, null, System.currentTimeMillis());

    Location location = new Location(PROVIDER_NAME);
    location.setLatitude(latitude);
    location.setLongitude(longitude);
    location.setAltitude(altitude);
    location.setBearing(bearing);
    location.setSpeed(speed);   
    location.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
    locationManager.setTestProviderLocation(PROVIDER_NAME, location.getLocation());
}
```

Comment: To use a mock location you have to put in your manifest that you want to work with mock locations-  it's a separate permission.  Are you sure that google maps has that permission?  It may have decided not to use mocks on purpose.

Comment: Thank for your help. I guess they have it since in other mock programs like in 'fake my location' its works.

Comment: My guess is that the Google Map's Activities/Fragments take action when they are brought to the foreground to avoid being victim of location spoofing.

Mock LocationProviders take effect system-wide, which also means that another app could remove the mock provider that your app added.  If you go back to Waze after looking at Google Maps, does Waze still  receive your mock GPS location updates?

Answer (score 3):

You should rather use `GoogleMap.setLocationSource(LocationSource source)` for providing random locations to the latest Google Maps SDK on Android. Use a random location source like this:

```
// In your MapFragment implementation or similar
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
    map.setLocationSource(new MockLocationSource());

MockLocationSource.java:
public class MockLocationSource implements LocationSource {

    private static final float ACCURACY = 1; // Meters
    private static final int MAX_SPEED = 10; // m/s
    private static final LatLng CENTER = new LatLng(59.91127, 10.70834);
    private static final double DELTA_LAT = 0.0005;
    private static final double DELTA_LON = 0.0005;

    private static final long UPDATE_PERIOD = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(2);

    private final Handler handler = new Handler();
    private LatLng lastCoordinate = CENTER;
    private OnLocationChangedListener listener;

    private void scheduleNewFix() {
        handler.postDelayed(updateLocationRunnable, UPDATE_PERIOD);
    }

    private final Runnable updateLocationRunnable = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Location randomLocation = generateRandomLocation();
            listener.onLocationChanged(randomLocation);
            scheduleNewFix();
        }
    };

    public Location generateRandomLocation() {

        Location location = new Location(getClass().getSimpleName());
        location.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
        location.setAccuracy(ACCURACY);
        location.setBearing(randomizer.nextInt(360));
        location.setSpeed(randomizer.nextInt(MAX_SPEED));
        location.setLatitude(lastCoordinate.latitude + scaleOffset(DELTA_LAT));
        location.setLongitude(lastCoordinate.longitude + scaleOffset(DELTA_LON));

        lastCoordinate = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

        return location;
    }

    private final static Random randomizer = new Random();

    private double scaleOffset(double value) {
        return (randomizer.nextDouble() - 0.5) * value;
    }

    @Override
    public void activate(OnLocationChangedListener locationChangedListener) {
        listener = locationChangedListener;
        scheduleNewFix();
    }

    @Override
    public void deactivate() {
        handler.removeCallbacks(updateLocationRunnable);
    }

}
```

Comment: Some devices does not have Google Maps SDK.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the help.
I found the problem, seems that goggle requires to set the Accuracy when other's apps don't need it
so adding the line `location.setAccuracy(1);` It solved the issue.