# Spoof Google Maps Location

Tags: android, google-maps, location, google-maps-android-api-2

I've been working on a Location Spoofer to get more familiar with Android programming and I've noticed that my app doesn't seem to spoof Google Maps. It works well for Facebook and a few other apps that I've tested, but even with Wifi and GPS turned off, Google Maps knows my exact position rather than my spoofed one. I downloaded another spoofing app from the Play Store (FakeLocation) and it also doesn't seem to trick Google.

This person seemed to have the same issue ([Android Mock location don't work with google maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15071199/android-mock-location-dont-work-with-google-maps)), but they apparently were able to fix it by setting the location accuracy. I tried that, and I also tried implementing the other answer. Neither of them works correctly with Google Maps.

How can I trick Google Maps into using my fake LatLng values?

Answer (score 1):

There's a permission ALLOW_MOCK_LOCATIONS that you have to specify in your manifest to get mock locations.  Google maps doesn't specify it.  It hasn't worked with any mocker I've ever used.

Comment: Weird that Google Earth is able to get mock locations but Google Maps can't...but thanks for your response anyways!